# Windows 10 is not booting after I installed Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot

When I power on my laptop, I see the boot menu. However, when I select Windows 10, it doesn't start, it shows only a black screen.

My Ubuntu 18.04 is booting fine.

How can I restore the possibility to boot into Windows 10?

Comment: Might be a duplicate. However, this question is phrased much more clearly, indicating what the user experiences. Other question just mentions "Unable to boot into windows" without indicating wheter the grub menu appears or not, whether Windows is an entry in the grub menu, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your Windows bootloader may have been corrupted. You can solve the issue with the steps below.

1. Insert a bootable USB/DVD of Windows
2. Boot using that bootable USB/DVD
3. Select the "Repair my computer" option that you will get after clicking the install button.
4. If that does not work (error message "Windows failed to repair", then open a command prompt using 'advanced options' and run the following 3 commands

   `bootrec /fixmbr`
   `bootrec /fixboot`
   `bootrec /rebuildBCD`
5. Restart your computer and check whether it works or not.

Comment: After this, you will need to repair the bootloader grub. Otherwise, you will not be able to start Ubuntu because the menu where you choose the OS you want to boot will not anymore be enabled.